# Problemas en render de datos django con annotate

Tags: python, django

En la view.py tengo una consulta así

```
ing =ingresos.objects.filter(pk=id_jovenclub).values('natural').annotate(sum=Sum('natural'))
```

en el template esta así

```
{{ ing}}
```

y me devuelve estos valores

**[{'sum': 1066.0, 'natural': 1066.0}]**

Porque los datos salen duplicados y otras como logro desaparecer los caracteres [{}]

*ojo eso solo pasa con annotate pues con aggregate obtengo el valor limpio*

Comment: Prueba con {{ ing.sum }}. Si obtienes un valores duplicados, es porque tu los estás solicitando así. Sin un __[mcve]__, es casi imposible comprender tu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver, primero lo de los caracteres [{}].
La función `filter` siempre regresa una lista por ello los corchetes []. Si sólo esperas un resultado lo que podrías hacer en el template es algo como

```
{{ ing[0] }}
```

Las llaves interiores significa que es un campo dentro de la consulta, si sólo quieres obtener un campo podrías hacer lo siguiente.

```
{{ ing[0].sum }}
```

Siendo `'sum'` un campo de la consulta.

Lo segundo.
Necesitaría ver los registros en la BD para estar seguro pero posiblmente lo que esté pasando es que sólo haya un valor en `'natural'` (que es 1066.0), es decir al hacer la suma de todos los `'natural'` sólo encuentra uno por lo que el resultado de la suma es el mismo. Esto tiene sentido porque primero estás filtrado por la PK `id_jovenclub` y este registro sólo tiene una columna `'natural'`.

Espero haberme dado a entender y que encuentres la solución a tu problema.

Comment: Genial gracias!!!!!!!!!